# VBA call to get value of entire row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new in excel macros and need to extract data from entire row, if you select any row. Suppose there is a sheet having following data:

```
s.no amount account

1    1234    1234

2    2345    6359
```

If I select 1st row 1 then it gives value of entire row :

```
1   1234  1234
```

I have tried a lot to extract value but I am unable to get value.

Comment: `I have tried alot to extract value` - show please what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to loop through the cells in the row and concatenate the values.  There is no function that I'm aware of that returns the "value" of the row.  For example:

```
Dim objSheet As Worksheet
Set objSheet = Sheets(1)
Dim intLastCellIndexInRow As Integer
intLastCellIndexInRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
Dim i As Integer
Dim strRowValue As String

For i = 1 To intLastCellIndexInRow
    strRowValue = strRowValue & " " & objSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i)
Next

MsgBox strRowValue
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing your inputs. It is working. I have another query to ask, I need to add a check , if user selects multiple rows then an error pop up should come with message that select only one row. I have tried a lot to implement but i couldn't reach to the perfect one. Please help!! it would be highly appreciable.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please ask this in a separate question by clicking the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

The Value of a row is an array of the values in that Row

```
RowData = Range("A1:C1").Value
```

would fill the Array "RowData" the same as the code

```
RowData = Array(1,1234,1234)
```

If you wanted a String like what rory.ap had answered, you use Join

```
'Same Msgbox result as rory.ap's Answer     
strRowValue = Join(RowData, " ")
MsgBox strRowValue
```

So to get a row as a Space (" ") separated string in one line

```
strRowValue = Join(Range("A1:C1").Value, " ")
```

Now I put in the Range "A1:C1" because your data is Columns A thru C

The Entire Row 1 is the Code

```
Rows(1)
```

But that Includes EVERY Column until the MAX, Which we really don't want in our string or even need to deal with.

Excel can Detect your data by using the .CurrentRegion from a Starting Point. So if we use A1 as our starting point, get the CurrentRegion and then limit it to the first row we'll only get the Columns used.

```
 Cell("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1)
 'Is Equivalent to Range(A1:C1) on your Data Example
 Cell("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(2)
 'Is Equivalent to Range(A2:C2) on your Data Example
```